# Say I have a column with width of max 20 px and i need to wrap the content within the given width

Tags: css

if I have a long text with / or some other escape sequences how to break this and display it in UI/?.

sample I/p:Welcome To/Programming
if I have a long text with / or some other escape sequences how to break this and display it in UI/?.

```
column1
{
  width:50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;(or) overflow-wrap :break-word (or)
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

expected o/p :the value should reside within the given width

```
Welcome
To/
Programming
```

but it's showing as

```
Welcome
To/Prog
mming
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you intend to do, can you provide your actual code and/or create a code snippet replicating what you mean?

Comment: I am rendering a table with 5 columns and setting width for each column except the last one.If the content of other columns overflows automatically it will impact the last one.So i tried applying word break for 1st 4 columns.Say if i have a text as 'HomeCareTaker/Companion"  am getting 'homecare then Taker/Co and then mpanion.But need to break it like HomeCare/ and Companion and show it in UI.Is there a way to do it? Note:no adjustment in font size and all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this, changing your markup and CSS a bit, you can use the pseudo-element `::before` and tell your text to break at a specific place by setting the content of the pseudo-element to `"\A"`

```css
.column1
{
  width:50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.column2
{
  width:50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.break:before {
    content:"\A";
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1">
  Welcome To/ Programming
</div>

<div class="column2">
  <span>Welcome</span><span class="break">To/</span><span class="break">Programming</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks better,but i am receiving the content dynamically that too array of strings.So i don't wish to add class in between the content.Is there an option to apply the break class to entire content.Like "<div class="column2 ">
  <span class="break">Welcome To/Programming</span>
</div>".Tried the above one it doesn't work.